# How to create a smooth progress bar animation

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I have this Tab component that slides between 2 pages after 15 seconds. I'm using a progress component to show the interval duration before it slides to the next page. I've successfully done all these but my problem is the animation of the progress as its value increases. It has a janky and sort of low frame rate animation. How can I make it as smooth as possible?

Here's a minimal recreation of said component: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/keen-browser-xts6kf

Answer (score 0):

To make high-frame rate animation or smooth animation you should add :

```
animation: loading 15s linear infinite;
```

Here property `linear` is for smooth animation.

---

There are many type of animations which you should try once like :p

```
linear - Specifies an animation with the same speed from start to end
ease-in - Specifies an animation with a slow start
ease-out - Specifies an animation with a slow end
ease-in-out - Specifies an animation with a slow start and end
cubic-bezier(n,n,n,n) - Lets you define your own values in a cubic-bezier function
```

### CSS/HTML Code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap'); 
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  }

body{
    background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}

.card{
    height: 190px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color:burlywood ;
    margin: 5px;
}

.card h2{
    margin: 10px;
}

.card p{
    margin: 10px;
}

.card .progress{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    animation: loading 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loading{
    0%   {background: red; width: 0px; }
  100% {background: red; width: 300px; } 
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="q6.css" />
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="title">
            <h2 class="heading">Crypto lending</h2>
            <div class="progress"></div>
            <p>Increase crypto deposits and conversion rates by understanding assets held off other platforms with real time and enriched historical data of your users. </p>
        </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Feel free to comment if you don't get any part of code :)